# Mathematica 14 scaling issues on linux gnome wayland

Tags: linux

**System: Ubuntu Linux 22.04.3, gnome wayland desktop.  Monitor 3840x2160**

I recently installed Mathematica 14.  I've had gnome-tweaks set to magnify fonts by a factor of  1.5.  Unfortunately, that no longer has an effect on the MMA window with 14.  (Still works fine with 13.3.)  Window menu items (file, etc), for example, are in a very small font (as well as the startup logo).

If I switch gnome to x from wayland, the window is fine, although I get the choppiness documented in other questions.

**Has anyone seen this problem?**

As a side issue, the Benchmark drops by about .5 when I switch to x.

Comment: So X is slower than wayland? Is not that expected though?